# ¿Cómo convertir un stream de audio a un archivo wav?

Tags: python, windows, wav

```py
def getStream(frec, duration):
    NF = int(BITRATE* duration)
    RF = NF % BITRATE
    WD = ''
    for x in range(NF):
        WD = WD + chr(int(math.sin(x/(BITRATE/frec)/math.pi))*127 + 128))

    for x in range(RF):
        WD = WD + chr(128)

    return WD

file = open('sound.wav', 'wb')
file.write(getStream(440, 2))
```

Cuando abro el archivo aparece en windows player:

*El Reproductor de Windows Media no puede reproducir el archivo. Es posible que el Reproductor no admita el tipo de archivo o el códec usado para comprimir el archivo.*

Comment: En la librería estándar tienes un módulo que se llama `wave` que te permite leer y crear ficheros en formato *\*.wav*. En el ejemplo hay varios errores, `BITRATE` no está definido, errores de indentación y exceso o defecto de paréntesis en la línea `WD = WD+chr(int(math.sin(x/(BITRATE/frec)/math.pi))*127+128))`. También es necesario que hagas un `file.close()` para poder leer el fichero generado. Supongo que estás en Python 2.x, habría que indicarlo en las etiquetas ya que el mismo ejemplo en Python 3.x dará errores.

Comment: @kikocorreoso ¿Podrías convertir tu comentario en una respuesta?

Comment: @astrojuanlu No hasta que no se especifique mejor lo que debe ir en `WD` ya que la indefinición de los paréntesis en `WD = WD+chr(int(math.sin(x/(BITRATE/frec)/math.pi))*127+128))` no permite definir correctamente lo que se quiere en `WD`. También, habría que especificar la etiqueta para python2.x o Python 3.x ya que el código resultante será diferente en ambos casos. Mejor esperamos la reacción de Hector para proceder.

Comment: la declaración de la variable WD era lo de menos (los escribi solo para dar una idea de lo que hacia y no me preocupe de los parentesis) solo quería saber como guardar lo que extraía de esa función pero gracias por ayudarme ya lo solucione importando wave y guardandolo :D

Comment: Perfecto entonces!!

Comment: @HectorSeguro también puedes autoresponder a tu pregunta para que veamos cómo lo has hecho entonces, por si puede ser útil a más gente :)

Comment: @HectorSeguro, por favor, publica tu respuesta y también puedes aceptarla. Gracias.